# Delimited List of Integers

Tags: java

This is the original prompt:

Write program that gets a comma-delimited String of integers (e.g. “4,8,16,32,…”) from the user at the command line and then converts the String to an ArrayList of Integers (using the wrapper class) with each element containing one of the input integers in sequence. Finally, use a for loop to output the integers to the command line, each on a separate line.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Parser {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList<String> myInts = new ArrayList<String>();
        String integers = "";

        System.out.print("Enter a list of delimited integers: ");
        integers = scnr.nextLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < myInts.size(); i++) {
            integers = myInts.get(i);
            myInts.add(integers);
            System.out.println(myInts);
        }
    }
}
```

I was able to get it to where it accepts the list of delimited integers, but I'm stuck on the converting piece of it and the for loop, specifically printing each number to a separate line.

Comment: Use `Integer.parseInt()` to convert from `String` to `Integer`...

Comment: Use the split method for a string and loop through the results added the parsed integers (Integer.parseInt(value)) into your ArrayList of Integers.

Comment: You are printing the whole list. You should iterate over each element and print each one in a loop.

Comment: Your `myInts.size()` is 0 as the list is empty until you put something in it.

Comment: I am still very confused on where what to add to my code? Is there any way that someone could clarify where things go?

Comment: Just take out your `for` loop and put @Mureinik's code in its place.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to convert this string would be to split it according to the comma and apply `Integer.valueOf` to each element:

```
List<Integer> converted = Arrays.stream(integers.split(","))
                                .map(Integer::valueOf)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Printing them, assuming you **have to** use a `for` loop, would just mean looping over them and printing each one individually:

```
for (Integer i : converted) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

If you don't absolutely have to use a `for` loop, this could also be done much more elegantly with streams, even without storing to a temporary list:

```
Arrays.stream(integers.split(","))
      .map(Integer::valueOf)
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you can convert the input string to `String[]`, by using the `split` method: `input.split(",")`. This will give you an array where the elements are strings which were separated by `","`.

And then, to convert a String to an `Integer` wrapper, you can use:

1. `Integer i = Integer.valueOf(str);`
2. `Integer i = Integer.parseInt(str)`

Answer (score 0):

myInts is empty, your data is in integers.
I suggest that you search about the fonction : split (from String)