# Extracting integer from a string

Tags: java, string, class, object, int

Hi I am just starting to learn java and i am stuck on a problem.
The problem states that  if we have a string S

```
S = "123:456:789"
```

We have to extract the numbers 123 ,456,789 separately and store them in different variables such as

```
int a=123
Int b=456
Int c=789
```

How can we do that?

Comment: Split on the colons, parse the fragments use `Integer.parseInt`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delimited List of Integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36161343/delimited-list-of-integers)

Answer (score 1):

You can `split` them by the `:` character and then save parse the Strings and save them in an array as follows:

```
String S = "123:456:789";
String[] arr = S.split(":");
int[] integers = new int[arr.length];
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
     integers[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string based on a delimiter into a string array. Once you have the string array you can access each array's element to get the specific values.

```
String S = "123:456:789"
String[] example = S.split(":");
```

Source: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2017/01/how-to-split-string-based-on-delimiter-in-java.html

Answer (score 0):

Look at the method split() in String, and into Integer.parseInt().
You also need to look into [Regular Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)